# Android user interface elements usage

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

*I did search the internet to find an answer to my questions but there are no websites that did help me, so I hope someone can! Thank you in advance and have a nice day :-)*

So these days I've been busy to get more into the Android Design guidelines and to learn more about it and how to implement it in my future applications. This is the main website I use to see what the guidelines are: http://developer.android.com/design/index.html. Great website but there are a few small things I just can't find in the dev guide or somewhere else. I just don't know how to implement some (simple) UI elements.

**Can someone provide me code snippets of the following questions?** (I want to know how to do it as simple as possible, how Google ment it!) It can help other (starting) developers too!

My main question is, are there special elements to achieve these things? As they are the key element in Android 4.0 it should have this things as some standard right?

1) Android 4.0 is using titles with dividers a lot in there new theme and it's looking great. But I can't find how to do implement this element simple like it should. What I want to know is how to make this blue title text with the grey looking divider underneath it look at this picture:

[image: Blue title with divider!]

2) How to make section dividers in general? Like this image:

[image: Section dividers]

3) How to make a list with section dividers and give a list-item a 2-line explanation under it's name like this:

[image: Listview]

*I did search the internet to find an answer to my questions but there are no websites that did help me, so I hope someone can! Thank you in advance and have a nice day :-)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases how you are going to have to do it is create a custom layout. I tried recreating  the look of the `people` application this way. for the most part the look you are going for is similar to the `PreferenceActivity`view. That gives you the look of the last image and probably how it was done in the `People` application with some extra programming. I just found it easier to create my own layout though instead of trying to mess around with that.

To my knowledge there is nothing in the api to create what you are looking to do easily and custom layout are going to be the way to go.

the custom dialog layout like you show in the beginning is very simple to do so if you dont know how to do manipulate layouts I would start there. look up the android color swatches to get the color of that blue

**Edit**

another thing you could do is look through the `People` source code and see how they did it but it will probably be more of a pain than what its worth when you can just do a layout

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will do it the way you say. Although it's stupid that they introduce a brand new standard with the guidelines we have to follow but that they don't include something in the API. But that's my opinion. Thank you! :)

Comment: Just an update to this, I found a library that does what you are looking for and is pretty easy to implement https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders